# Whether Ribbon tool bar button will work in Home page tab of Tridion?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I implemented a Ribbon tool bar button for Format page of Tridion 2011 sp1 version. Now my requirement is to move the Ribbon button to Home page - Edit Group and make it work. For that I changed pageid to "FormatPage" and groupid to "EditGroup". It is enabled in home page. For Format page RTFfield I used "FaCommand". For Home page simple text field which command need to be used?
Config. Code:

```xml
<ext:extension assignid="EditGroup" pageid="HomePage" name="RTF Extensions">
  <ext:group/>
  <ext:apply>
    <ext:view name="ComponentView">
      <ext:control id="ItemToolbar"/>
    </ext:view>
  </ext:apply>
</ext:extension>      

<!-- BUTTONS -->
<ext:extension pageid="HomePage" groupid="EditGroup" 
               name="Ribbon&lt;br/&gt;Button" assignid="InsertAttribute">        
  <ext:command>InsertAttribute</ext:command>
  <ext:title>Ribbon Button</ext:title>
  <ext:dependencies>
    <cfg:dependency>InsertAttributeExtension.InsertAttribute.Commands</cfg:dependency>
  </ext:dependencies>
  <ext:apply>
    <ext:view name="ComponentView">
      <ext:control id="ItemToolbar"/>
    </ext:view>
  </ext:apply>
</ext:extension>
```

My button javascript:

```
Type.registerNamespace("RTFExtension.Commands");
RTFExtension.Commands.IA = function Commands$IA(name) {
    Type.enableInterface(this, "RTFExtension.Commands.IA");    
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Cme.Command", [name || "IA"]);
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Cme.FaCommand", [name || "IA"]);
};
```

For FormatPage and RTF field I used

```
FACommand
```

But for simple text field which command need to be used?
 Please help in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use firebug to find the PageId of a particular group in the html source of the tridion dialog.  HomePage does seem right. I would have also thought if the value was blank this is where the button will show up.

I will update this answer shortly with a solution if this doesn't help in the short term.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes, PageId and GroupId are identified by firebug tool itself. Please tell me how to make it work in home page? Do we need to use any extra command in button JS? For simple text field how can we make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my component creation page I have multivalued Embedded schema fields. To access the complete XML of the component I am using the command: "$display.getView().getItemFields()" . For a particular RTF field I am using the command: "target.editor.getHTML()" . But my requirement is to get the complete set of Embedded field values. Which command I need to use? Please help in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ User - can you create a question for your second comment?

Comment: I posted a question related to the second comment. Please find the same at below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715078/how-to-get-the-complete-set-of-embedded-field-values-in-a-popup-window-in-the-tr